# Finding distance between two points in the plane, given by cartesian co-ordinates

Tags: java, distance, points, plane, cartesian-coordinates

I know what is the formula for finding the distance but I dont understand why my program doesnt work? This is my code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      double res = dist(0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 4.0);
      System.out.println(res);
    }
    private static double dist(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
         return Math.sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1)-(y2-y1)*(y2-y1));
    }
}
```

And instead of getting 4.0 as a result I get 0.0?! Can someone explain me why?

Comment: Math.sqrt((4)*(4)-(4)*(4)) = 0.0

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug in your dist function. The distance should be the square root of the sum of the squares not the difference. Change it to the following.

```
return Math.sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1)+(y2-y1)*(y2-y1));
```

Also your result should be 4*sqrt(2) not 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

The distance is about `5.656854`, not 4. Try `Math.sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1)+(y2-y1)*(y2-y1))`. The formula is `a^2+b^2=c^2` (a squared + b squared = c squared), so you need to use `+`, not `-`. This change will make it work. Your're passing a negative number to `Math.sqrt()` otherwise.